# Matlab generating random numbers and overlap check

Tags: matlab, random

I wrote a code for generating random number of rods on Matlab within a specified domain and then saving the output in a text file. I would like to ask for help on adding the following options to the code;
(i) if the randomly generated rod exceeds the specified domain size, the length of that rod should be shortened so that to keep it in that particular domain.
(ii) i would like to avoid the overlapping of the newly generated number (rod) with that of the previous one, in case of overlap generate another place for the new rod.

I can't figure out how shall I do it. It would be of much help if someone may help me write code for these two options. 
Thank you

```
% myrandom.m  
% Units are mm.

% domain size
bx = 160;
by = 40;
bz = 40;

lf = 12; % rod length
nf = 500; % Number of rods

rns = rand(nf,3);      % Start
rne = rand(nf,3)-0.5;  % End

% Start Points
for i = 1:nf
    rns(i,1) = rns(i,1)*bx;
    rns(i,2) = rns(i,2)*by;
    rns(i,3) = rns(i,3)*bz;
end

% Unit Deltas
delta = zeros(nf,1);
for i = 1:nf
   temp = rne(i,:);
   delta(i) = norm(temp);
end

% Length Deltas
rne = lf*rne./delta;

% End Points
rne = rns + rne;


fileID = fopen('scfibers.txt','w');
for i = 1:nf
    fprintf(fileID,'%12.8f %12.8f %12.8f\r\n',rns(i,1),rns(i,2),rns(i,3));
    fprintf(fileID,'%12.8f %12.8f %12.8f\r\n\r\n',rne(i,1),rne(i,2),rne(i,3));
end
fclose(fileID);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would start from writing a function that creates the random rods:

```
function [rns,rne] = myrandom(domain,len,N)

rns = rand(N,3).*domain; % Start  --> rns = bsxfun(@times,rand(N,3),domain)
rne = rand(N,3)-0.5;  % End

% Unit Deltas
delta = zeros(N,1);
for k = 1:N
  delta(k) = norm(rne(k,:));
end

% Length Deltas
rne = len*rne./delta; % --> rne = len*bsxfun(@rdivide,rne,delta)

% End Points
rne = rns + rne;

% remove rods the exceed the domain:
notValid = any(rne>domain,2); % --> notValid = any(bsxfun(@gt,rne,domain),2);
rns(notValid,:)=[];
rne(notValid,:)=[];
end
```

This function gets the `domain` as `[bx by bz]` and also the length of the rods as `len`, and `N` the number of rods to generate. Note that using elementwise multiplication (`.*`) I have eliminated the first `for` loop.
In case you use MATLAB version prior to 2016b, you need to use [`bsxfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

> In MATLAB® R2016b and later, the built-in binary functions listed in this table independently support implicit expansion.

The affected lines are marked with `-->` in the code (with the alternative).

The last three lines in the function remove from the result all the rodes that exceed the domain size (I hope I got you correctly on this).

Next, I call this function within a script:

```
% domain size
bx = 160;
by = 40;
bz = 40;
domain = [bx by bz];
lf = 12; % rod length
nf = 500; % Number of rods

[rns,rne] = myrandom(domain,lf,nf);
u = unique([rns rne],'rows');
remain = nf-size(u,1);
while remain>0
    [rns_temp,rne_temp] = myrandom(domain,lf,remain);
    rns = [rns;rns_temp];
    rne = [rne;rne_temp];
    u = unique([rns rne],'rows');
    remain = nf-size(u,1);
end
```

After the basic definitions, the function is called and returns `rne` and `rns`, which are probably smaller than `nf`. Then we check for duplicates, and store all unique rods in `u`. We calculate the rods remain to compute, and we use a `while` loop to generate new rods as needed. In each iteration of the loop, we add the newly created rods to those we have in `rne` and `rns`, and check how many unique vectors we have now, and if there are enough we quit the loop (then you can add printing to the file).

Note that:

1. I was not sure what you mean by *"in case of overlap generate another place for the new rod"* - do you want to have more than `nf` rods if some are duplicates, that from which `nf` are unique (what the code above does)? or you want to remove the duplicates and remain only with `nf` unique rods? In the case of the latter option, I would insert the `unique` function part into the function that creates the rods `myrandom`.
2. The wile loop as written above is not efficient since no preallocating of memory is done. I'm not sure that this is possible if you just want to create more rods but keep the duplicates, but if not (the second option in 1 above) and if you are going to use this allot, then preallocating is very recommended.

Comment: I saved the function as myrandom.m and named the script file as main.m and then ran the main in matlab, I had the following error, Error using  .* 
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in myrandom (line 3)
rns = rand(N,3).*domain; % Start

Error in main (line 9)
[rns,rne] = myrandom(domain,lf,nf);

Comment: Is it ok if I add the same lines of adding the printing to the file as in my first post codings?

Comment: Assuming `rns` has three columns, you have to make sure that the argument `domain` is a 1-by-3 vector, otherwise, the [multiplication by implicit broad casting](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/compatible-array-sizes-for-basic-operations.html) won't work.

Comment: You can add the same lines for printing to the file, and it should work properly. Notice that there are more convenient ways to write delimited files, like [`csvwrite`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvwrite.html?s_tid=doc_ta), [`dlmwrite`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html), and [`writetable`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writetable.html).

Comment: I used the default values of the domain as shown in the code (bx=160; by=40; and bz=40;) which I think is a 1-by-3, but still the error is present

Comment: What version of MATLAB do you use? Is it before 2016a?

Comment: I am using 2016a

Comment: Then you need to use [`bsxfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html): `rns = bsxfun(@times,rand(N,3),domain);`

Comment: Thank you for the change but still have some issue at the following,

Error using  > 
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in myrandom (line 19)
notValid = any(rne>domain,2);

Error in main (line 9)
[rns,rne] = myrandom(domain,lf,nf);

Comment: This is the same issue, I just forgot to update this line. See the edit in the answer.

Comment: I mean to sequentially adding rods into a domain, while checking for contact interferences with all previously generated rods, until the defined volume fraction or nf is reached.
By contact interference check I mean to verify rod interferences, a minimum distance of say 2.5 times the rod radius between two rod axes. (Later I will be needing it to properly mesh the rods and the space between them).

Comment: If a newly added rod interfered with another rod, the position of the new rod is
altered/translated just enough to respect the inter-rod distance limit. If the translation resulted in interferences with other rods, the new rod is to be removed and repositioned randomly in the same volume. We continue this cycle until the new rod location was free from interferences.